# Can't launch localhost after index.html and path is changed

Tags: javascript, angular

my localhost is not launching. I changed index.html to index.php, then also changed launching path in angular.json

```
"options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/webas",
        "index": "src/index.php",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
```

my localhost `http://localhost:4200/` after `ng serve -o` can't be reached/opened  
Im using VScode, angular7

Comment: You do realize that `ng serve` is not a PHP server right? There can't be any PHP there.

Comment: I have face the same problem almost. `PHP` file may not run your url

Answer (score -1):

plz edit `index` to `"index": "src/index.html"`
if you want to run it in Php server, you can run `ng build --prod` and copy the dist folder to `xampp/htdocs` then open it ( here you should rename `index.html` to `index.php` )